GRASS GIS from server taking hours to import a shapefile
I have a large shapefile (1GB) with 12k features. It takes 8 minutes to load in R studio (v.4.3.3) using terra package (v.1.7-71), function vect(), on a Windows machine with 32GB of RAM and an Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4790 CPU @ 3.60GHz processor. I am trying to load it in GRASS GIS (v.8.2.1) on a server running Fedora 37 with 64 CPUs using v.in.ogr. It is taking more than 5 hours to register primitives, clean and break polygons, break boundaries... I don't understand why there is such a time difference. Projection is Mollweide and I set, before importing, the resolution to 10km (res=10000) with g.region. The server is used by other people and almost all the CPUs are pretty busy, constantly, but there are always at least 8-10 CPUs free. What can I check to understand where this delay is coming from?

That's an odd comparison to make. Why not stay within the same framework and compare the results with different hardware only? In other words: How long does it take to load on Windows using GRASS? Or on Fedora making use of {terra}?

Because I usually use R from my PC and GRASS GIS from a server. It takes 10 seconds to load the file on Fedora with terra.

Sounds like its trying to clean your polygons and you have very dirty polygons? Is it quicker to load in GRASS if you use -c to not clean polygons?

Definitely. I tried to load it with the -c flag and it took few minutes. I got several warnings on Number of centroids exceeding the number of areas, number of incorrect boundaries, duplicate centroids... I will try to import it with the snapping threshold suggested.

Or load it into R or QGIS and try making a "clean" version there. Try using functions like st_is_valid and st_is_simple to see possible problems, or use QGIS' cleaning functions...
